# What is the relationship between Angelou's poem "Caged bird" and book "I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings"?

Tags: poetry, title, intertextuality, maya-angelou, i-know-why-the-caged-bird-sings

What is the relationship between the poem ["Caged bird"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/48989/caged-bird) and the book [*I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Know_Why_the_Caged_Bird_Sings)? One seems to be an autobiography and the other a poem, but they have overlapping titles and I'm unclear which was written first or whether the poem inspired the book or whether the poem is in the book or what other possible relationship.

Comment: Which "Caged bird" poem are you talking about? I assume Angelou's? Note that Wikipedia claims that the book was titled as a reference to a different poem: ["Maya Angelou titled her autobiography I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings (1969) from a line in Dunbar's poem "Sympathy", at the suggestion of jazz musician and activist Abbey Lincoln."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Laurence_Dunbar)

Comment: Yes, her poem. And I saw that. Which only adds to my confusion.

Comment: Please [edit] anything relevant you've found into the question. While it's not useful to say "I Googled and found nothing" or similar, because that's too general, telling us where you specifically researched and what you found will help answerers know what they have to address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[I Know Why the Caged Bird Sings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Know_Why_the_Caged_Bird_Sings)* was the first volume of Maya Angelou's autobigography, which eventually grew to seven volumes. Published in 1969, the title is taken from the third stanza of Paul Laurence Dunbar’s poem, *[Sympathy](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46459/sympathy-56d22658afbc0)*:

> I know why the caged bird sings, ah me, 
> When his wing is bruised and his bosom sore,— 
> When he beats his bars and he would be free;
> It is not a carol of joy or glee, 
> But a prayer that he sends from his heart’s deep core, 
> But a plea, that upward to Heaven he flings— 
> I know why the caged bird sings!

According to an interview quoted in *Heart of a woman, mind of a writer, and soul of a poet : a critical analysis of the writings of Maya Angelou* by Lyman B. Hagen, Angelou confirmed the origin of the title, explaining "I think it was a bit of naivete or braggadoccio. . . to say I know why the caged bird sings! **I was copying a Paul Laurence Dunbar poem** so it’s all right." The caged bird is clearly a metaphor for the lack of freedom, suffered by both caged creatures and slaves.

Angelou's poem *The Caged Bird* was published fourteen years later in 1983, in her poetry collection *[Shaker, Why Don’t You Sing?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaker,_Why_Don%27t_You_Sing%3F)* The poem again deals with themes of repression and confinement, and so Angelou again returned to the metaphor of the caged bird, describing the struggle of African-Americans for freedom. Beyond this reuse of the metaphor, however,there appears to be no other link between the two works.